Is SSL connection of plugins default?
If WordPress installation runs with SSL, is it guaranteed, that plugins, if they establish connections to remote hosts, use SSL by default too?

the answer is no. Incoming conneection have nothing to do with outgoing ones

No, this is not something that can be guaranteed, setting up an SSL certificate on your own site and using https: for everything does not guarantee that code that calls to other sites will use https or TLS/SSL. Assuming those remote services even support HTTPS or speak HTTP.
Your SSL certificate is for securing inbound HTTPS communication to your server with an incoming connection, it has nothing to do with outbound connections to 3rd parties and remote hosts.
The only way to be sure is to audit the plugin, code review, and test.
